# castng number value issue in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have few column as below, I am comparing combination of A&B with C&D like 1.58 & 1.60 but I don't know when we are doing comparison for few column comparison come in wrongly for example in below chart in shows that 1.58 is bigger than 1.60 while for 1.98 and 1.110 it is working fine, would u mind help me what is the issue? I think it should be due to casting problem.

```
A |  B  | pathA   |   C  |  D   | pathB |  Path Equal? |  Version      
1 |  58 |  C:\    |   1  |  60  |  C:\  |     Same     |     L

1 |  96 |  C:\    |   1  |  110 |  c:\  |     Same     |     G
```

I used below code for path equal and version column:

W1 = Path equal: `=IF(X1=Y1,"Same","Not Same")`

version: `=IF(M28="same",IF(VALUE(CONCATENATE(E28,".",F28))=VALUE(CONCATENATE(K28,".",L28)),"E",IF(VALUE(CONCATENATE(E28,".",F28))>VALUE(CONCATENATE(K28,".",L28)),"G",`

Comment: You are comparing strings. `"158"`<`"160"` -> version = `"L"`, `"196"`>`"1110"` -> version = `"G"`. It is not clear, what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: I got what is the problem, but I don't know how to solve it, actually it should become 1.58 and 1.60 and 1.96 & 1.110 and then I want to compare them.

Comment: hi, if you use `=IF(G2="same",IF(CONCATENATE(A2,B2)*1=CONCATENATE(D2,E2)*1,"E",IF(CONCATENATE(A2,B2)*1>CONCATENATE(D2,E2)*1,"G","L")))` you will get over the problem. I do not know if there is more professional way to achieve this but multiplying values with 1 convert them to numbers :)

Comment: btw when you use `CONCATENATE(A1,B1)` you will get 158 instead of 1.58, please keep this in mind. you may need yo use `(A1 & "." & B1) depending on your language settings "." may change to ","

Comment: I modify my formula but still same issue I have

Comment: Even if you compare `1.96` and `1.110` you shouldn't expect `1.110` to be bigger.

Comment: yeh but how to solve it, actually these number represent version of the objects, therefore if they are bigger show that it is newer

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of a table with sample rows and expected result?

Comment: check my answer, the problem was with formula, I solve it by using below formula and compare all the number one by one

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by change my formula in this way:

```
=IF(M2="same",IF(A2=C2,IF(B2=D2,"E",IF(B2>D2,"G","L")),IF(A2>C2,"G","L")),"False")
```